# Add a "mapview" in a webOS app

Tags: dictionary, webos

I'm not familiar yet with WebOS dev (just started this weekend) but I didn't find any "MapView" widget in the reference library.

Is there any way to include a WebView in my app or do I have to start the map app from my app ?

Thanx.

Comment: xcuz : "...any way to include a MapView" not a "WebView"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps V3 API to just include a map view in your application.  To see an example, look at the FourSquare application's [source code on GitHub](http://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-palmpre).  Also, you can check out [this article at bchilds.com](http://bchilds.com/blog/2009/10/06/dynamically-loading-google-maps-on-the-palm-pre) for info on how to load the Google JavaScript for their maps API efficiently.

If you want to launch the separate Google Maps application, you can do that using a Mojo service call to the application manager.  Here's an example:

```
this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.applicationManager', { 
  method: 'launch', 
  parameters: { 
    id: 'com.palm.app.maps',
    params: { 
      location: {lat: 37.759568992305134, lng: -122.39842414855957, acc: 1}, 
      query: "Pizza"
    } 
  }  
});
```